# set continueOnError property to true through java code

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to update a batch of records in MySql DB using the connector `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar`. As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11298360/2270563), the driver may continue in case of failure of one record or it might throw exception.

> The JDBC driver may choose to attempt to execute all the statements in the batch if one statement fails or it may choose to stop executing statements in the batch once a statement fails.

As per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) of the connector jar, it says that `continueOnError` is by default true.

> **continueBatchOnError**
>
> Should the driver continue processing batch commands if one statement fails. The JDBC spec allows either way (defaults to 'true').
>
> Default: true
>
> Since version: 3.0.3

I want to change this properties value according to some business logic. So how can I set this property to true or false in my implementation (in my java code).

Note: I cannot change the connection parameter. I just obtain a `connection` object and execute the batch update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection is a `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection`  you can set the `continueBatchOnError` flag:

```
JDBC4Connection mysqlCon = (JDBC4Connection)con;
boolean current = mysqlCon.getContinueBatchOnError();
mysqlCon.setContinueBatchOnError(false);
```

Else (e.g. if the connection is wrapped by a connection pool implementation) you can use `Connection.unwrap` to get the `JDBC4Connection`.