# Hibernate batch update is turned on but still executes eache query seperatly

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, batch-insert

I'm trying to add a batch update to my spring boot project. The batch seems activated, but when I check the hibernate logs, there are still multiple queries.

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
```

**hibernate stats**

```
295647400 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
3693300 nanoseconds spent preparing 21 JDBC statements;
5752515000 nanoseconds spent executing 20 JDBC statements;
1275544900 nanoseconds spent executing 4 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
1287992700 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 19 entities and 0 collections);
735000 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 1 entities and 1 collections)
```

**hibernate log**

```
2022-10-09 19:21:16,192 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger: insert into SYSTEM.SNAPSHOT (CREATED_ON, ENTITY_PROPER_NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
2022-10-09 19:21:16,192 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl: Reusing batch statement
2022-10-09 19:21:16,192 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger: insert into SYSTEM.SNAPSHOT (CREATED_ON, ENTITY_PROPER_NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
2022-10-09 19:21:16,192 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl: Reusing batch statement
2022-10-09 19:21:16,192 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger: insert into SYSTEM.SNAPSHOT (CREATED_ON, ENTITY_PROPER_NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
2022-10-09 19:21:16,193 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl: Reusing batch statement
2022-10-09 19:21:16,193 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger: insert into SYSTEM.SNAPSHOT (CREATED_ON, ENTITY_PROPER_NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
2022-10-09 19:21:16,193 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl: Reusing batch statement
2022-10-09 19:21:16,193 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger: insert into SYSTEM.SNAPSHOT (CREATED_ON, ENTITY_PROPER_NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
2022-10-09 19:21:16,193 DEBUG org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger: Executing batch size: 5
```

I'm expecting hibernate to generate a statement like this below for Oracle Database.

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO Snapshot ( created_on, entity_proper_name, id ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )
    INTO Snapshot ( created_on, entity_proper_name, id ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )
    INTO Snapshot ( created_on, entity_proper_name, id ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )
SELECT 1 FROM dual;
```

When I'm checking the executed statement into Jprofiler or directly into Oracle, it's the same as shown in the hibernate logs. The execution count is also the same as it should be if you run inserts separately.

[image]

> Does the Hibernate batch work for the Oracle database?

---

### **Code snippets**

```
Spring Boot v2.7.1 
Spring v5.3.21
Java 17.0.3.1
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/db
    username: user
    password: password
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
        format_sql: false
        jdbc:
          fetch_size: 100
          batch_size: 5
        order_updates: true
        order_inserts: true
        batch_versioned_data: true
        generate_statistics: true
```

**Snapshot entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SNAPSHOT", schema = "SYSTEM", catalog = "")
public class Snapshot {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
    private String createdOn;
    ...
}
```

**Snapshot service**

```
@Transactional
    public void execute() {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < snapshots.size(); i++) {  
        snapshots.get(i).setFieldValue(fieldValue);
        snapshots.get(i).setCreatedOn(createdOn);
    }

    snapshotRepository.saveAll(snapshots);
       ...
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
    <version>21.7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't expect hibernate to use the special multiple-insert syntax, which is vendor specific. It rather uses so called (sometimes) array operations, which sends a parameterized query with an array of values (rows), which the oracle jdbc driver [does support](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/859759_1.html). Here's a [random oracle article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18555/ch_ten_insert_multiple.htm#TDPPH177) mentioning the stuff, but all major dbs have that possibility and here's some [jdbc sample code](https://www.netjstech.com/2018/01/batch-processing-in-java-insert-update-batch-queries.html) using it (without hibernate).

That's also sound with all your logs. Jdbc says it ran 4 batches for 20 inserts, with 5 rows per batch. Any speed up comes from reduced network round trips and only one lookup or parse operation per batched update in the db. Oracle's sql engine still does 1 insert per row with all associated pomp and circumstance, like constraint checking and index maintenance. The only way known to me to get around that is the oracle loader with direct path mode.

But to verify that oracle actually uses batched statements is an issue, since its a data transfer feature. The sql engine will run separate statements again.

For identical data one should see a significant speed increase of some 50% at least, although that may depend on the type of data inserted. [This evaluation](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2013/05/batch-writing-and-dynamic-vs.html) speaks of 500% compared to non-batched operations, but that's not much of a proof. You could provoke a database error for a defined number of rows on insert and [then check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298220/jdbc-batch-insert-exception-handling) the exception raised (should be some `BatchUpdateException`) and the actual number of rows processed. That might be enough of evidence that batching took place at the client side. Also a breakpoint in the jdbc code may do, `OraclePreparedStatement.sendBatch()` would be a candidate I guess. And perhaps you could debug the oracle executable. You'd have to use a connection that doesn't use the thin client, like you do (`jdbc:oracle:thin...`), but the OCI client (oracle call interface), [the call you're searching](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/250494/bulk-insert-via-oci) for is `OCIBindArrayOfStruct`. For the db server side I have no idea honestly. Perhaps one could sniff out the IP traffic to determine the number of requests per n rows.

As far as I'm concerned, I took the speed up for identical data as sufficient evidence, that batching took place. And even if it didn't, just the speed up was all I needed.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I was able to get `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12899 ....` by sending a larger size of the column value. It means that batch works because it's an ORA error which is provided by Oracle.

Comment: @JiboOne nice. wouldn't mind if you'd accept the answer by clicking the green check mark, if it solved your issue. Did you run it via hibernate or bare jdbc? But acutally ORA-12899 indicates a column size violation, not anything batch-related. Only jdbc claims batch. Do you trust the whole thing so far? It could still just *pretend* to batch, while not batching at all. But that would be reflected in many posts, articles and law suits already barring sort of global jdbc batch conspiracy. But usually users are fine with a speed up, even if there is no proof for the type of mechanism used.

Comment: Actually, personally I'd trust a breakpoint in the (decompiled) oracle jdbc driver (OraclePreparedStatement.sendBatch()) as much as I'd trust Oracle as such.

Comment: I ran it by hibernate. I could not see the batch-styled query (parameterized query, as you said) but compared to the JPQL query, which commits a transaction (no batching) on each execution, and the second version by the `saveAll` method. The execution time was 2x faster in the case of 'saveAll'. If I set `batch_size: 0` and use `saveAll,` then the execution time is almost the same as JPQL execution  (it executes inserts/updates separately). So from this, I can guess that batching is working in the case of  `saveAll` and `batch_size: more than zero`.

Comment: Btw a commit per transaction spoils the the performance of course, and the comparison too somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of the **allocation size** provided by Hibernate.

In your entity class can you try changing the allocationSize?

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SNAPSHOT_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SNAPSHOT_SEQ", sequenceName = "SNAPSHOT_SEQ", allocationSize = 150)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

Comment: Nothing changed in terms of structure and count of insert queries

Comment: can you check if SNAPSHOT_SEQ is created in the db?

Comment: yes it's created, and nextVal increases by 150

Comment: The problem is not only on insert. The update works the same way.